# Set a string value for drawable

Tags: java, android, string, drawable

How can I replace this

```
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagesample);
```

with the value of String img? *(value of String img is the name of the image in res drawable)*

**My Code:**

```
     String img = "sampleimage";


     // code for image in pop-up dialog

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
            View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            final ImageView subImageView = (ImageView) subView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagesample);
            subImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    // code for a pop-up dialog
    
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Congratulations");
            builder.setMessage("Thanks for helping me!");
            builder.setView(subView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            builder.show();
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? And I'm not even quite sure what you want to do here?

Comment: I want to use a value of the variable instead using the direct id of the image resource
@s_o_m_m_y_e_e

Comment: You cannot access the resource file like in the way you want. Your current code is perfect and would give the perfect result.

Comment: Yes . I know that it is working perfectly, I just want to know if there are parts of the code that can be replaced in order to use the string value as source instead of the resource id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Possible. What you are trying to do is simply not possible.

The `getDrawable` method accepts an `int` argument. And you are trying to pass a `string`. You can not call a method with wrong type of argument.

Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources for further reference.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the code in a different way but with the **same output**, yet the source of image is the string value ? If possible, please refer something. Thanks

Comment: Like a alternative code just for the value of the string but with the same output (image inside a dialog)

Comment: As I already said, It can't be done using a string.